# How to send $_POST data from form to function with other variables?

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to pass data from a form to another function in another file, but this function already has other variables that is coming from another function.

```
<form method="post" action="data.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://www.website.com/">
    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="description of website">
    <input type="hidden" name="image" value="http://www.website.com/image.jpg">
    <input type="hidden" name="board_ids" value="$board_ids">
</form>
```

### data.php

```
<?php
    function login()
    {
        random variables with cURL included which is passing data to the post function

        post($ch, $cookie, $url);
    }

    function post()
    {
        uses $ch, $cookie, $url.
    }
?>
```

Now, above function login(), I have the following..

```
$post_url       = $_POST['url'];
$post_desc  = $_POST['description'];
$post_image    = $_POST['image'];
$board_ids      = $_POST['board_ids'];
```

PS: board_ids is an array with a few specific id's, ex: `$board = array('102938', '483756', '002938', '239384');`

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($board_ids); $i++ )
{
    post($board_ids[$i]);
}
```

I want to know how I can send the $post_url, $post_desc, $post_image and $board_ids to the post() function.

I was actually wanting to make post() run each time with each board_id array, is that possible? the above keeps saying I have `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2` on the post function. Been at it for 9 hours straight and can't pass the variables to the post function, had to ask for help.

EDIT

```
<?php
foreach($pinterestClass->retrieveAllInfo() as $data)
{
    echo '
    <tr>

        <form method="post" action"data.php">

            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="post_url" value="'.$data['p_Url'].'">'.$data['p_Url'].'
            </td>

            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="post_description" value="'.$data['p_Description'].'">'.$data['p_Description'].'
            </td>

            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="post_image" value="'.$data['p_Image'].'">'.$data['p_Image'].'
            </td>

            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                <section id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" onclick="firstDropDown(this)">
                    <span class="anchor">Boards</span>
                    <ul class="items">';?>
                    <?php 
                        $p_iD = $data['p_iD'];
                        $checkedBoards = $oClass->pCheckedBoards($p_iD);

                        foreach($pClass->retrieveBoards() as $data)
                        {
                            $boardiD    =   $data['boardiD'];
                            $boardName  =   $data['boardName'];

                            $checked = '';

                            for($i = 0; !$checked && $i < sizeof($checkedBoards); $i++)
                            {
                                if($checkedBoards[$i]['board_iD'] == $boardiD)
                                {
                                    $checked = 'checked="checked"';
                                }
                            }

                            echo '
                                <li><input '.$checked.' type="checkbox" name="post_board_id" value="'.$boardiD.'">'.$boardName.'</li>
                            ';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php echo '
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </td>

            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                Status
            </td>

            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                <div style="background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px rgb(229, 229, 229); padding-top: 5px; height: 22px;">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <input name="post_info" type="submit" class="btn btn-xs default" value="Edit">
                </div>
            </td>

        </form>

    </tr>
    ';
}
?>
```

### data.php

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $post_desc  = $_POST['post_description'];
    $post_url   = $_POST['post_url']';
    $post_image = $_POST['post_image'];

    $board = $_POST['post_board_id'];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($board); $i++ )
    {
        $board[$i];
    }

    function pinLogin()
    {
        $username   = '';
        $password   = '';

        $Cookie = '/cookie.txt'; //cookie session

        // this is the http post data for logging in - username & password are substituted in later
        $login_post     = array(
            'source_url' => '/login/',
            'data' => '{
                "options":{
                    "username_or_email":"%s",
                    "password":"%s"
                    },
                "context":{}}',
        );

        // cURL so it needs $ch, $url is the login url

        pinPost($ch, $Cookie, $url);
    }

    function Post($ch, $pinCookie, $url)
    {
        $boardId    = $board[$i];
        $postDesc   = $post_desc;
        $postUrl    = $post_url;
        $postImage  = $post_image;

    }


    Login();    

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you're calling `pinPost`, but you function is actually named `Post`.  Rename it to:

```
function pinPost($ch, $pinCookie, $url)
```

Second, your `pinPost` function is receiving three parameters it never uses (`$ch, $pinCookie, $url`).

Third, your `pinPost` function is trying to use four variables that are never passed to it:

```
function Post($ch, $pinCookie, $url)
{
    $boardId    = $board[$i];
    $postDesc   = $post_desc;
    $postUrl    = $post_url;
    $postImage  = $post_image;

}
```

Where are `$board[$i]`, `$post_desc`, `$post_url`, and `$post_image` coming from?

Finally, if you want to access those variables in your `pinPost` function, just directly access them like this:

```
function pinPost()
{
    $postDesc   = $_POST['post_description'];
    $postUrl    = $_POST['post_url']';
    $postImage  = $_POST['post_image'];
    $boardId    = $_POST['post_board_id'];

}
```

You might want to read some PHP tutorials, specifically concerning functions.  This is pretty basic stuff that you'll want to really understand.

Comment: But it does not allow me because in the login function there are variables passing it from it to the post function, look in the login(), there is $ch, $cookie, $url... I understand the most part, but this has gotten me confused, since in login function it's passing other variables. So when login is runned, the post will run after it.

Comment: @iBrazilian2 Edit your question and include your actual code.

Comment: There it is there is some code missing because it's way too long to post here so it would be crazy but that's exactly it.

Comment: PS: quickly edited as I included the code I was testing but that's the original now.

Comment: @iBrazilian2 I made some changes.  But seriously, you should follow a PHP tutorial on this stuff.  It would make it a lot clearer to you.

Comment: It does use "$ch, $pinCookie, $url", I just removed it because it was a lot of code, I mean a lot so it would be huge to post it here. But the post function really does use all three variables, I even put it in a comment "// cURL so it needs $ch, $url is the login url".

Comment: Ok, leave them in.  Does the rest of that make sense to you?

Answer (score -3):

For post tag you need a sumbit button or ajax submittion.

For example:

```
<form method="post" action="data.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://www.website.com/">
    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="description of website">
    <input type="hidden" name="image" value="http://www.website.com/image.jpg">
    <input type="hidden" name="board_ids" value="$board_ids">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button> // submit button
</form>
```

Or using jquery

```
$("#theForm").ajaxForm({url: 'data.php', type: 'post'});
```

Also I would suggest on data.php page usng if(isset(variable)) statment to check if variable exists

Comment: What does the question have to do with AJAX?